# Solve: $2^{3x}-3^x-2^{3x-1}3^{x+1}=-288$

Tags: exponential-function

$$2^{3x}-3^x-2^{3x-1}3^{x+1}=-288$$
I have a problem doing exponential functions. I find it really hard. I really tried doing this and I cant find anyway to getting close to a result.I factored it every way possible and still cant see anything. Can somebody give some hint and give some tips how to solve these kind of problems easier?

Comment: Is your equation right so?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Right from the book

Comment: We have
$$
\left(\frac13+\frac{8^x}2\right)(2-3\cdot3^x)=\frac23+8^x-3^x-8^x3^x\cdot \frac32
$$Maybe that helps?

Comment: Isn´t there a typo? Could it be $2^{3x}3^x-2^{3x-1}3^{x+1}=-288$?